# Another 3-way switch problem

Tags: electrical

I have a setup as follows: power, switch 1, switch 2, light. Wires are power to top of switch one, travelers from switch 1 to 2, and top of switch 2 to lignt.

For the following, I will call switch 1 power sw1-p, and the travellers sw1-t1 and sw1-t2, and switch 2 similarly.

I'm testing the switch screw against ground.

Testing results are as follows:

```
Switch 1 up   Switch 2 up   ---> light on
sw1-p  120v   sw2-p   120v
sw1-t1  35v   sw2-t1   35v
sw1-t2 120v   sw2-t2  120v

Switch 1 up   Switch 2 down ---> light off
sw1-p  120v   sw2-p     0v
sw1-t1 120v   sw2-t1  120v
sw1-t2 120v   sw2-t2  120v

Switch 1 down Switch 2 down ---> light off
sw1-p  120v   sw2-p     0v
sw1-t1   0v   sw2-t1    0v
sw1-t2   0v   sw2-t2    0v

Switch 1 down Switch 2 up   ---> light off
sw1-p  120v   sw2-p     0v
sw1-t1   0v   sw2-t1    0v
sw1-t2   0v   sw2-t2    0v
```

These results baffle me. What is the problem? How do I fix it?

Comment: How did it come to be this way? What's the backstory?  Can you shoot us photos of the wiring on the inside of each box, and post them?  We need to know a lot about wire groupings into cables, and wire colors. How are you identifying common vs traveler screws?

Comment: See the two answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you have misidentified the terminals of the switches and miswired appropriately. I believe what you have identified as traveler 2 is actually the common “p” terminal. When switch one is down, your t1and t2 are connected and p is floating. Your second case is switch 2 feeding voltage back to switch 1.

By the way, the 35 volts is phantom voltage being picked up by your high impedance voltmeter.

Comment: You are correct. I read another question/answer on the site, and realized my error - darkest screw is power, others are travellers.

Answer (score 4):

The poster (me) was an idiot. I read a wiring diagram for 3-way switches in a book explaining code and assumed all switches were set up the same.

When I actually wired the switches correctly as was explained on the box, they worked as expected.

My problem was that I expected the top terminal to be power, and the bottom 2 to be travelers. However, the bottom right was power, and the other 2, 1 top and 1 bottom were travelers. The power was identified with a black screw and the travelers with the usual brass.

Comment: As we say in the computer business, [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM). Glad you got it working.

Comment: Actually, I did read the manual, just the wrong one.